# Whether I should use value directly or delay composation by passing a lambda in Jetpack's Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm struggling in thinking whether I should pass a value to a composable function or a lambda. Let's take a look at my example. Please skip the `LaunchedEffect`, it's just for simulating mutable data.

**My questions is: In this case, should I use `ComposableTextDirect` or `ComposableTextLambda` and why?**

```
@Composable
fun ComposableContainer() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (isActive) {
                delay(1_000L)
                aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse = Date().toString()
            }
        }
    }
    Column {
        ComposableTextDirect(text = aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse)
        ComposableTextLambda {
            aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun ComposableTextDirect(text: String) {
    Text(text = text)
}

@Composable
fun ComposableTextLambda(provider: () -> String) {
    Text(text = provider())
}
```

I have tried the above code, and it works well and is the same as the others.

Comment: I can’t spot any behavior differences unless you count the extra functional object that is generated each time you call the lambda version.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I just wonder whether to pass directly the value or pass the value by a lambda to avoid recomposition.

Comment: using lambda is one of suggestions to improve performance, but in most cases it's redundant and only complicates your code, so use it if you really have performance issues because of often updates - e.g. using animatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically in the way you wrote it, it will not make any difference, but note one thing. If you modify your code like this:

```
@Composable
fun ComposableContainer() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (isActive) {
                delay(1_000L)
                aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse.value = Date().toString()
            }
        }
    }
    Column {
        Text(text = "Test")
//        ComposableTextDirect(text = aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse.value)
        ComposableTextLambda {
            aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse.value
        }
    }

}
```

There will be difference. Just look at the layout inspector and recompositions. Text will be recomposed multiple times in case you use

```
        ComposableTextDirect(text = aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse.value)
```

and it will not be recomposed in the case you use

```
  ComposableTextLambda {
            aTextThatCanBeChangedBySomethingElse.value
        }
```

Reason for this is that each time you observe mutable state in some composable you will have recomposition of it each time value change.

Long story short, use mutable state in the lowest level you can to avoid recompositions.

Comment: Thank for your very detailed answer. So you mean If possible, I should use `ComposableTextLambda` to reduce recomposition? But I think it will make the code becomes more complicated. I think `ComposableTextLambda` still get recompositon when the text changed. But with lambda, it reduce the composition scope, right?

Comment: Yes, basically in that case, it would be more complicated, so it would be easier for you to move your mutable data inside ComposableTextLambda. There are, of course, time when this will not be possible, and that is ok also, but recompositions will happen more often on upper levels.